# replace whitespaces from string

Tags: c#

When I call

```
string t = tmp.Replace(@"\n", "").Replace(@"\t", "");
```

where `tmp` is a string-literal containing sth. like this `'\n\t\t\t\t\tmirDochLatte'` (consider also the single-quotes that are part of the string) the result-string `t` remains unchanged.

Where do I miss to delete the whitespaces from my input?

Btw.: hence the actual string may or may not contain valid spaces I am searching only for tabs and new-lines.

Comment: Instead of `@"\t"` use simple `"\t"`. The former means a string of "slash" and "t", while the latter is single "tab" character, and you want that.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl is right. Consider `"\r"` as well.

Comment: aaah, yeap... that´s it, thanks :D

Comment: Voting to close since that's "simple typo".

Comment: If the whitespaces only appears at the beginning or end of the string, consider using the `Trim` method of the string

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: I think that it is more than just a typo, it's a misunderstanding of how the verbatim operator works.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: so maybe then try marking it as a proper duplicate?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Okay. Have to agree on that.

Comment: @joe The OP states that there is a single quote at the beginning and end of the string, so `Trim` would not work here.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing literals and escaped characters. What `@"\n"` in fact really is, is this literal: `\n`, not the line end you expected.

Try removing the verbatim operator `@`:

```
string t = tmp.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\t", "");
```

I would suggest to remove `\r` too, since Windows line ends have both `\r` and `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `tmp` string actually seems like this (I assume it is not a *verbatim string literal*);

```
'
                    mirDochLatte'
```

`\n` is new line, `\t` is tab character.

And this string doesn't have any `\n` or `\t`, there is character to replace it.

You should use [escape sequence characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) as a [regular string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), not a verbatim string literal.

```
string s = "'\n\t\t\t\t\tmirDochLatte'";
string t = s.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\t", "");
Console.WriteLine(t); // 'mirDochLatte'
```